# Unable to install QT5 .run file on ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, 32-bit, qt5

I know that to install `.run` files, I need to do

```
chmod +x qt.run
./qt.run
```

But it seems the ubuntu is not trying or able to run the executable. I even tried appending the `sudo` but it doesn't work. Interesting thing is that after I have made the file executable and then I type `./` and press tab, its not even giving that file (there is only one executable in the directory).

PS : I downloaded the executable file from [here](http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/) .

**EDIT**

I have downloaded the offline installer for linux 32 bit and the exact file name is `qt-opensource-linux-x86-5.5.0.run`

Answer (score 3):

You do not mention that you have the file renamed after download. Therefore:

```
chmod +x qt-unified-linux-x64-online.run
./qt-unified-linux-x64-online.run
```

---

Or all steps

```
cd
wget http://download.qt.io/official_releases/online_installers/qt-unified-linux-x64-online.run
chmod +x qt-unified-linux-x64-online.run
./qt-unified-linux-x64-online.run
```

And you will see this

[image]

Comment: This did the trick in Ubuntu 16 for some reason the versoin I downloaded from their site wasn't letting me `chmod` the permissions, but this one did.